# Tabulator leaves the changes made after Tabulator loading

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using "tabulator-tables" "version:4.0.4".

A translate function is called on a front end to translate some the visible data of the tabulator table after the tabulator is loaded on the screen with the data. Everything worked as expected.

The issue is when resizing the browser screen or open window inspect element, tabulator leaves the changes made after tabulator loading(like translate function) and show the raw data which we received from the back end.

help required: how to save the changes which don't leave its effect on browser resizing or on opening inspect element.

Refer the screenshot for reference:

[image]

CODE:

```
async function columnTab(searchData = "", lmt) {
    searchData = searchData ? searchData : await fetchReqUrl("search", `?limit=${lmt}`, "fetch", "POST", "viewform");    
    searchData = (JSON.parse(searchData));     //data fetched from back end
    let DataCollHead = searchData.columns
    let slNo = [{ title: "Sl No.", formatter: "rownum", align: "center", width: 80 }]
    DataCollHead = slNo.concat(DataCollHead)
    let DataCollList = searchData.tableData
    table = new Tabulator("#searchContainer", {
        // movableRows:true,
        columns: DataCollHead,
        layout: "fitColumns",
        pagination: "local",
        paginationSize: 20,
        clipboard: true,
        clipboardPasteAction: "replace",
        clipboard:true,
        clipboardPasteAction:"replace",
        responsiveLayout: "collapse" , 

    })
    var tableData = DataCollList;
    table.setData(tableData);

    let resultRow = dgei('searchContainer')  //function to translate the data
    resultObj()
    formatResult(resultRow);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of your code, we won't be able to help otherwise. Please read [ask]

Comment: We will need to see the code you are using to fully diagnose it, but from your description it looks like you are trying to manipulate the contents of your table from outside of Tabulator. Because Tabulator uses a virtual DOM any changes you try to make from outside the table will be replaced whenever the table is redrawn, on resize for example. you should be using the inbuilt formatters to alter the table structure. if you post the translate functions you are using and a description of what you want to achieve, i can show you how to integrate them into a formatter

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is because you are trying to manipulate the data in the table from outside, the table.

Because Tabulator uses a virtual DOM you cannot safely edit its contents from outside without it being overwritten when the table is redrawn.

If you want to alter the data as it is entering the table you need to use the [Mustator](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/mutators#mutators) functionality.

If you want to alter how the data is displayed to users you need to use the [Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/format) functionality